# XML to XLS copy current element at the end of element

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<items>
    <item>
        <count>3</count>
        <name>Name</name>
        <description>Description</description>
    </item>
</items>
```

need to append 2 extra child at the end depending upon the count. if count is 3 add two       child. Please help me to write the XLS for me. am new to the XSLT.
Desired Output:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<items>
    <item>
        <count>1</count>
        <name>Name</name>
        <description>Description</description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <count>1</count>
        <name>Name</name>
        <description>Description</description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <count>1</count>
        <name>Name</name>
        <description>Description</description>
    </item>
</items>
```

Answer (score 0):

In xslt 1.0 recursive template should be the way, like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <items>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="items/item" />
        </items>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <!-- Call multiplication template for current item -->
        <xsl:call-template name="multiply">
            <xsl:with-param name="item" select="." />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- recursive named template to ensure multiplication -->
    <xsl:template name="multiply">
        <xsl:param name="item" />
        <!-- If count is not passed in as a parameter take it from item param -->
        <xsl:param name="count" select="$item/count"/>

        <item>
            <count>1</count>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$item/name" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="$item/description" />
        </item>

        <!-- Check if still needed to multiplicate -->
        <xsl:if test="$count &gt; 1">
            <!-- Recursive call-->
            <xsl:call-template name="multiply">
                <!-- for the same item -->
                <xsl:with-param name="item" select="$item" />
                <!-- but decreasing number of copies -->
                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count - 1" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Probably there should be checked if count is not zero or negative number or empty or different type than number or ... But the principle should be same.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you need to work with XSLT I suggest you read some tutorials to help you understand the syntax of XSLT. For example do the tutorials on W3Schools.

Here is a XSLT that gives you the needed output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- When <count> equals 3, create to extra <item> elements, with the same value of this current <item>, but default <count> to 1 -->
    <xsl:template match="item[count=3]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
        <item>
            <count>1</count>
            <name><xsl:value-of select="name" /></name>
            <description><xsl:value-of select="description" /></description>
        </item>
        <item>
            <count>1</count>
            <name><xsl:value-of select="name" /></name>
            <description><xsl:value-of select="description" /></description>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Reset the <count>3</count> element to value 1 -->
    <xsl:template match="count[text()=3]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

If you want to do all recursively and independed on the `<count>` element, but always execute it when the `<count>` is bigger than 1, then use the next template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- When <count> is greater than 1, duplicate the <item> elements occording to the <count>, with the same value of this current <item>, but default <count> to 1 -->
    <xsl:template match="item[count &gt; 1]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="multiply">
            <xsl:with-param name="count" select="count" />
            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="name" />
            <xsl:with-param name="description" select="description" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Reset the <count> element to value 1, when the <count> element is greater than 1 -->
    <xsl:template match="count[text() &gt; 1]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Recursive template -->
    <xsl:template name="multiply">
        <xsl:param name="count" />
        <xsl:param name="name" />
        <xsl:param name="description" />

        <xsl:if test="$count &gt; 1">
            <item>
                <count>1</count>
                <name><xsl:value-of select="$name" /></name>
                <description><xsl:value-of select="$description" /></description>
            </item>

            <xsl:call-template name="multiply">
                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count - 1" />
                <xsl:with-param name="name" select="$name" />
                <xsl:with-param name="description" select="$description" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Probably won't work for other count value than 3...?

Comment: It won't work when the count is bigger than 3. The question is also (I quote): "need to append 2 extra child at the end depending upon the count. if count is 3 add two child"

Comment: "**if** count is 3 add two child" ... I just supposed it is only an example but might be it is fixed requirement. Only original poster knows what is right.

Comment: @JirkaŠ. OK that's true. I read it diffently. I updated answer also with recursive template